# go back(traverse up) from "this" and find specific element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal, dom-traversal

Even with jQuery traversing from a specific point is sometimes a riddle to me.

**My HTML Structure looks like this:**

```
<div class="grid__area grid__area--empty">
    <div id="streamcontainer" class="streamcontainer">
         <div class="inputer">
            <form action="">
               <input type="text" name="purl" value="XXX" id="" class="">
               <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="submiturl"> //starting "this" point
            </form>
         </div>
         <div id="player" class="player"></div> // The Endpoint
    </div>
</div>
```

The **starting point** is the clicked **#submit**.

The **Endpoint** should be **#player.**

What have I tried so far in many different variations:

```
$(this).find('.player').attr('id');
$(this).parent('.streamcontainer').find('.player').attr('id');
$(this).parent('.streamcontainer').closest('.player').attr('id');
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you're using parent instead of parents. $(this).parents('.streamcontainer').find('#player').  Also why are you trying to get the value of the player's ID when you already know it?

Comment: Did that sort it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the OP was accidentally using .parent() instead of .parents()

```
.parent():  traverses to the immediate parent of 

.parents(): allows us to search through the ancestors of these elements in the DOM tree
```

So I think what the OP was after originally was:

```
$(this).parents('.streamcontainer').find('.player').attr('id');
```

Unless this is an exercise in DOM traversal I'm not sure why you'd want to do this? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use (in my demo I used '#submit' but you can use this):

```
$('#submit').closest('.inputer').next();
```

**player** is the next sibling of the **inputer** anchestor .

```js
var ele = $('#submit').closest('.inputer').next();

console.log(ele.attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid__area grid__area--empty">
    <div id="streamcontainer" class="streamcontainer">
        <div class="inputer">
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" name="purl" value="XXX" id="" class="">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="submiturl"> //starting "this" point
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="player" class="player"></div> // The Endpoint
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

traverse back to the parent div with class inputer using $(this).parents('.inputer') and then find `.player` next to that div, so
you can use `$(this).parents('.inputer').next('.player').attr('id')`

```js
console.log($("#submit").parents('.inputer').next('.player').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid__area grid__area--empty">
<div id="streamcontainer" class="streamcontainer">
     <div class="inputer">
        <form action="">
           <input type="text" name="purl" value="XXX" id="" class="">
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="submiturl"> //starting "this" point
        </form>
     </div>
     <div id="player" class="player"></div> // The Endpoint
</div>
</div>
```